# Unable to locate package phpmyadmin - Ubuntu server 14.10

Tags: apt, apache2, 14.10, phpmyadmin

I have installed my old pc with UBUNTU SERVER 14.10

I run the command `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`

But is shows Unable to locate package phpmyadmin

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package phpmyadmin
```

I searched in askubuntu and tried many ways. But no use.

Please help.

Comment: Warning : Ubuntu 14.10 is  unsupported and its use is not recommended. It don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. You should install [a supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) like Ubuntu 14.04 or 15.10.

Comment: I would recommend using either `14.04 LTS` or `15.10`

Comment: There is no use trying to install because it most likely will not work. it's end of life was on July 23, 2015.

Comment: I was checking . Will install 14.04 soon
http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

This solved my problem.. Thanks